# Audio Playing too fast on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, audio

I did a total reset of my netbook (Asus eee pc 1201ha) and I installed Lubuntu 13.10. The matter is that, whatever player I use, my music files are always played too fast. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Run this and reboot:

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel position_fix=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

(Thanks to Temüjin, on [this ubuntuforums's post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181302&p=12819386#post12819386))